# HierarchicalDataTemplate Command Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, command

Good morning,  It seem to have hit a brick wall, as far as my understanding of binding.  I'm new to WPF and binding in xaml in general.  I'm trying to get the button in the treeview to execute a command in the ItemTree view model to draw items to the canvas... however I haven't got that far.

I'm not necessarily going to go with a "button,"  but I wanted to make sure my understanding of Command was clear... and obviously it's not!

The model for the tree is ItemsGroup, which contains the Name, Path, Children ... etc.

The error message is that it can't find the command in the ItemsGroup model.  I tried to change the DataType of the HierarchicalDataTemplate to the ViewModel, but that didn't work either.

The RelayCommand is mostly boilerplate, class that inherits ICommand.  However, it doesn't reach it since it's the Binding that is messed up.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Window:

```
public partial class ViewMain : Window
{
    public ViewMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModelMain();
        ItemTree.DataContext = new ViewModelItemTree();

        ...
    }

}
```

Window xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
   <TreeView x:Name="ItemTree" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" Height="334" Width="192">
      <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type model:ItemGroups}">
            <Button Content="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding DrawItemsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path}"/>
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
   </TreeView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

ViewModel (ViewModelItemTree):

```
    public RelayCommand DrawItemsCommand { get; set; }
    void ExecuteDrawItemsCommand(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter == null) return;

        ...
    }

    public ViewModelItemTree()
    {
        List<string> itemsList = DataLayer.GetItemsForTree();
        Children = new ObservableCollection<ItemGroups>(TreeLoad(itemsList));
        DrawItemsCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteDrawItemsCommand);
    }
```

Error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'DrawItemsCommand' property not found on 'object' ''ItemGroups' (HashCode=35751240)'. BindingExpression:Path=DrawItemsCommand; DataItem='ItemGroups' (HashCode=35751240); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  DrawItemsCommand is in the ViewModeItemTree view model - The parameter is a member of the  ItemsGroup model (which has the tree information.)  How do I get the target of the Command to point to the viewmodel, and use the parameter of ItemsGroup?  I'm trying to tell this button to go and search for this particular item (Path), and draw geometry on a canvas.

Comment: If your TreeView is a control within ViewMain, the *ViewModelItemTree* can be accessed through the TreeView's DataContext property. Use a binding with a RelativeSource using `FindAncestor`, like: `{Binding DataContext.DrawItemsCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}`

Comment: The TreeView's Datacontext is already being set via code-behind (see first code block.)  The {Binding Name}  Displays perfect as it's part of the ItemsGroup model.  However I want the command to point to the ViewModel, to actually run the command, right?  If I'm off-base, let me know.

Comment: Okay, yes, so the the TreeView has already the correct DataContext (a ViewModelItemTree obejct). Please refer to my last comment regarding how to do the command binding... the binding source of that command binding in my previous comment is the DataContext of the TreeView...

Comment: possible duplicate of [XAML Binding from ItemsControl Template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940589/xaml-binding-from-itemscontrol-template)

Comment: It worked!  Can you explain why this binding expression worked?  I'm still trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58551/discussion-between-elgonzo-and-logan-klenner).